# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module processed.jtoml not found using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am facing an error when executing basic Selenium Java program.

Code trials:

```
package vanakam;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Self {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\rdl\\Desktop\\Drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

This is my program while running showing below error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module processed.jtoml not found, required by org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver
```

How to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module processed.jtoml not found, required by org.seleniumhq.selenium.remote_driver
```

...implies that required *modules* and *classes* wasn't found during compiletime.

---

### Solution

This error can happen for many reasons and two most common reasons and their solutions are as follows:

- Deleting all the selenium jar files from the modulepath and adding them back all to the classpath instead.
- Ensure you are compiling your java program using *Java 1.8*.